# get the coordinates from vertices, using JUNG

Tags: graph, jung

How can i get the coordinates of my vertices in my graph after it is laid-out?,i'm using JUNG for creating and laying-out the graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `layout` of type `jung.algorithms.layout.AbstractLayout` or any subclass, you can call `layout.getX(vertex)` and `layout.getY(vertex)`. `vertex` is your vertex, whatever type you have chosen.

Comment: hey can i ask you something more..?i tried to do what you told me but i can't..Isn't Circle layout a subclass of AbstractLayout??